# Material UI expand in the content to take all over the grid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am rendering four different graphs. I had them appearing to be in the same height and width, but I had changed one of the grids to include 2 graphs instead of 1. I had the grid expand in height for it to fit in the graph. But now the other graphs have this big empty space at the bottom of the grid. How would I be able to expand my graph so it could take care of all the grid.

What I tried is using a style{{height: '100%'}}, but I guess that only takes care of the grid, not the graph.

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
        <Graph1/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4} style={{height: '100%'}}>
        <Graph2/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
        <Graph3/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4}>
        <Graph4/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

what I have in my Graph2-4 is the following

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
        <MyGraph/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12}/>
</Grid>
```

Not to sure how to expand the content to take care of all the grid

Answer (score 0):

You were half-way there I think. The parent grid should be `100vh` and each graph's parent grid `100%`

```
<Grid container spacing={2} style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
    <Grid item xs={4} style={{ height: '100%' }}>
        <Graph1 />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4} style={{ height: '100%' }}>
        <Graph2 />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4} style={{ height: '100%' }}>
        <Graph3 />
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={4} style={{ height: '100%' }}>
        <Graph4 />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Also for Graph2-4, I believe the 2nd `<Grid item xs={12}/>` can be removed, unless you saw a purpose.

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
    <Grid item xs={12} style={{ height: '100%' }}>
        <MyGraph />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: hmm, the grids seem to be expanding, but not the content inside the grid